# Magento SSL links not given out from Magento functions

Tags: magento, ssl, hyperlink

Im having an issue with SSL links in Magento.
I have SSL setup and working...all usual settings.

When i view the source of a page, i can still see HTTP links...and this is invalidating the SSL.

The urls in question (relating to currnecy, store switcher, navigation) are all given out by Magento functions.  Such as:

- getCategoryUrl();
- getSwitchCurrencyUrl();

Does anyone know what may be wrong...is their something i may have missed?
Need any more info, pls let me know...

thanks
Shaun

Comment: @R.S is right ... you can easy check if you have any http resources in the page with firebug or some similar tool. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good thing in the fact that it 'help' prevent search engine from seeing links to your catalog and product page as also been https (causing duplicate content). Also to my knowledge, only if you have resources (images, css, js) it will affect (invalidate) your ssl (because of browser cookies). If you view source on a page with ssl magento will automatically convert those resources to https